# Constructor and Destructor in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

Can you tell why i don't add "getch()" or "system("pause")", the result is right in the first code else in the second code  display to lack code in part destructor

```
    #include "iostream.h"
    class chucmung1
    {
     public :
         chucmung1()
         {
                    cout <<"chuc mung ban nam moi an khang thinh vuong\n";

         }
         ~chucmung1()
         {
                     cout <<"Nam Tan Ty\n";
         }


    };

  //  the first code
     int main()
     {
      chucmung1 object;
      system("pause > NULL");    
     }

  // the second code 
        int main()
     {
      chucmung1 object;
     }
```

In the first code, the result is 
 "chuc mung ban nam moi an khang thinh vuong"

In the second code, the result is 
"chuc mung ban nam moi an khang thinh vuong
 Nam Tan Ty"
In this case when console don't pause after display result.

Comment: please provide the exact output in both cases.

Comment: 1) Use <iostream>, not "iostream.h".  2) Run your program the way it should be run, and that is at the command-line, not in the IDE of the compiler.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are asking why nothing is displayed in the second case? Well, actually, I guess something is displayed, but the console window is immediately closed again so fast that you can't see it. As @PaulMcKenzie says, run it from the command line. Then it will not disappear immediately.

Comment: Why do these questions keep popping up from people who must have been hibernating in cryostasis between 1992 and now? Is the zombie apocalypse indeed upon us? (I hear Zombies love DevC++ and conio...)

Comment: The destructor from your `chucmung1` class instance `object` will be called at the exit point of the function `main`, where it has been created. If you insert a pause before it happens, you won't see immediately the IO side effects pertaining to it, as it is the case in the first implementation of `main`.

Comment: (1) `iostream.h` is pre-standard and won't compile with e.g. g++. Use standard `iostream` (no `.h`). (2) Preferentially use angle brackets, not quotes, for system headers. I.e. `<iostream>`. This avoids picking up a user-defined header of the same name. (3) To use the `system` function you should include `<stdlib.h>`. (4) `NULL` in not a device name in Windows, unless you have defined it yourself. The null-device in Windows is named `nul`. However, hiding the prompt from the `pause` command only causes confusion. (5) Best to not have a pause; run program via Visual Studio Ctrl+F5, or from cmd.

Comment: @KerrekSB it's worse if you follow the "C" tag , you see casts of malloc from people who must have been in cryostasis since 1978

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you tell why i don't add "getch()" or "system("pause")", the result is right in the first code

The `object` goes out of scope and is destructed when `main()` exits.  There is nothing in that code sample that is preventing `main()` from exiting, thus the `object` is being destroyed without delay.

> else in the second code display to lack code in part destructor

The `getch`/`pause` is delaying `main()` from exiting, and the `object` is still in scope at the time of the pause, so it is has not been destructed yet.

If you want the `object` to be destructed before pausing the code, you can put the `object` into another scope so it gets destructed earlier:

```
int main()
{
    {
        chucmung1 object;
    }
    system("pause > NULL");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output will be identical in both cases, albeit with the destructor running after the pause in the first case, provided you ***don't press control-C or control-break to get out of the pause***... that will terminate your program before the destructor gets a chance to run.